# Using bash to replace html character entities in the xml file

Tags: sed, xml, html

I have a string like this in xml file:

`&lt;h3&gt;Styled here with: &lt;a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','107723102')$"&gt;FRS blo&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','000482512')$"&gt;Os Cutes&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;and &lt;a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','000312901')$"&gt;Dor Sho&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</short-description>`

**I need to replace** `/p&gt` part with `/h3&gt`.

I tried to do this with the help of `sed` like below:

`sed -i -e 's/&lt;h3&gt;Styled here with\:.*\/p&gt;/&lt;h3&gt;Styled here with\:.*\/h3&gt;/g' new_exp_dev02.xml`

but this did not work at all and just doubled the result.

Maybe I forgot to escape some more symbols in order to replace `/p&gt` part with `/h3&gt` correctly?

Comment: bash is a powerful tool, but it's not a text editor; I replaced the tag accordingly.

Comment: I agree but I a have a lot of such strings in xml file where I need to replace tag `p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` can use nearly any character as a delimiter for its expression, I have found it best to not use a delimiter that is in the string one is attempting to replace to limit escaping mistakes.

`sed -e 's!/p&gt!/h3\&gt!g' new_exp_dev02.xml` would replace `/p&gt` with `/h3&gt`.  The ampersand (`&`) in the replacement needs to be escaped as that character has a special meaning in `sed` replacement expressions.

Your posted `sed` expression is very hard to read and I am not sure what you are attempting to achieve with it, but it seems to have a different goal then "replace `/p&gt` part with `/h3&gt`."

EDIT: if you have to write the expression in that long form, this should work:

`sed -e 's!\(&lt;h3&gt;Styled here with:.*\)/p&gt;!\1/h3\&gt;!g' new_exp_dev02.xml`

This puts the whole matched part aside from `/p&gt` into a back reference which we can use in the replacement section as `\1`.  You cannot use regular expression on the replacement side of a `sed` replacement, as regular expressions are only used for matching.

The first expression in this answer will replace all occurrences of `/p&gt` with `/h3&gt`, the second expression will only replace `/p&gt` if it occurs immediately after matching the regular expression `"&lt;h3&gt;Styled here with:.*"`

Comment: thanks @GracefulRestart! indeed `&` should be escaped. but the approach is still the same I've changed my expression a little bit. Here is ==> `sed -i -e 's/\&lt;h3\&gt;Styled here with\:.*\/p\&gt;/\&lt;h3\&gt;Styled here with\:.*\/h3\&gt;/g' new_exp_dev02.xml` but again the second part did not work correctly with regular expression and just replaced the left part with `Styled here with:.*/h3&gt;` and `.*` left as it was in replaced part instead of changing to the words it should have covered.

Comment: Yes - the dot loses its wildcard meaning in the replacement part. If you **REALLY** need that complicated search pattern, try using "back references". Escaping the `&` in the regex part is NOT necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below perl command

```
 perl -pne "s/p&gt/h3&gt/g" filename
```

output

```
&lt;h3&gt;Styled here with: &lt;a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','107723102')$"&gt;FRS blo&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','000482512')$"&gt;Os Cutes&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;and &lt;a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','000312901')$"&gt;Dor Sho&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;</short-description>
```